# Grant SharePoint Online Folder Permission to Group via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am able to grant permission to user in the SharePoint Online folder, but i am not able to grant the permission to a group, here is the code and result

```
$folder = Get-PnPFolder -URL "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Shared Documents/folderA"
$Role = Contribute
```

***Grant permission to User WORKS***

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission -list "Documents" -identity $folder -User "testuser01@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -AddRole $Role
```

***Grant permission to Group FAILED***

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission -list "Documents" -identity $folder -Group "Test-Group" -AddRole $Role
```

## Result

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission : Group cannot be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PnPfolderPermission -list "Documents" -identity $folder -Group "T ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-PnPFolderPermission], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.SetFolderPermission
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself, add the group to the folder with -User groupname@xxx.onmicrosoft.com. 
So -Group in this command is not valid, group name should use email address of the O365 group (e.g. Test-Group@xxx.onmicrosoft.com)

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission -list "Documents" -identity $folder -User "Test-Group@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -AddRole $Role
```

AAD group also supported (e.g. AADGroup01)

```
Set-PnPfolderPermission -list "Documents" -identity $folder -User "AADGroup01" -AddRole $Role
```